What part of an octal mode is the file type?
I've scoured the Internet as much as I could, and while I read in many places that the numeric mode of a file contains the file type, I couldn't find out which of these it is. If we use stat on a file like /bin/bash, st_mode is 100755 (octal), and on a directory like /home it is 040750, but on a symlink to these files and directories, it remains the same. I understand that the last three digits might change between files and directories but the first three digits seem to be fixed to just 100 and 040.

Use lstat() if you want to get the symlink's mode, not the target's mode.

To get the file type, use the S_IFxxx constants from <sys/stat.h>. See the sample code in the stat(2) man page
